# Use internal LB with Boxfuse

Tags: cloudcaptain

Is it possible to configure an app to use an internal AWS LB (classic)?

I have a bunch of apps running on custom LB's but they are all internet facing. I can't find my newly created internal LB in the Boxfuse console (LB picker dropdown)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use Internal ELBs just like any other classic ELB. Make sure that you created it in the correct region and VPC for the environment you wish to configure it for.

Comment: Yes, it appeared in the console after a couple of reloads :-)